# how to convert series(24 numbers) into datetime like Y/M/D H:M:S

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I want to convert 24 numbers series, like `20190919120426`, into date time, `2019-09-19 12:04:26`

Here are the `'Datatime'` series

```
0       20190919093350
1       20190919093350
2       20190919093357
3       20190919093357
4       20190919093517
5       20190919093517

import pandas as pd

for i in fl_std:
    x = i['Datatime'].astype(int)
    pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Convert `20190919093517` into `datetime type`

Answer (score 3):

change format with omit space and `:`, also loop here is not necessary, because is possible pass column to function:

```
df['Datatime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datatime'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print (df)
             Datatime
0 2019-09-19 09:33:50
1 2019-09-19 09:33:50
2 2019-09-19 09:33:57
3 2019-09-19 09:33:57
4 2019-09-19 09:35:17
5 2019-09-19 09:35:17
```